# How to partial sharing product code in company?

Tags: version-control, startup

I'm developing a app which would be my startup product. Surely, it has serverside and clientside code. Creating separate repository for each one is common task. When I work with someone, I'll give them authority to access their own repository.

But, when my project grows big, the needs for sharing partial codes would be arised. For example, when I hire someone as part-time job to maintenance some UI part of my product, opening all access to clientside code would be danger. Because he would be copy or get my product's essential idea in the business logic code.

It also occurs at serverside code. In the server, many control layers are mixed. When I hire someone, not a permanent worker of my company but as a part-time worker, I want to only give him a part of source code. Giving all access to product code is crazy because serverside code has lots of private keys and administrator datas.

I think that these problems are common to IT company like facebook or google. But I can't find any methodology or idea how to handle these problem. Can anyone teach me? Thanks.

Comment: Have a look [here](https://24ways.org/2013/keeping-parts-of-your-codebase-private-on-github/) to get started thinking about this.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Private repository is not an option. To me, it is mandatory.  But this is what I asked about.

Comment: I'm out of ideas.  I have upvoted your question and I hope you get an answer.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Ok, let's have an example. In your SO profile, you said that you are working on a company named "NEXTLABS". Your company selling some software products. Right?
Someday, one of the developers in your compony resigned, but still remains all the softwares source code in his own PC. One day, a rival company get a news about his resign and contact him to buy the source code. Then, how to prevent it?

Comment: I knows there are laws and contract to prevent the industrial thief. But as the essential idea reside in the source code, the rival company can take advantage of it and make more good product from it. 

I think the best way to prevent "Code thief" is give the developer only partial authorities to his related job task. In this way, the code which are not created by him are safely protected. Isn't it?

Comment: Don't make your code public then.

Comment: Ok. I found the exactly same question. Maybe I searched with wrong keyword.

http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/170246/how-to-prevent-code-from-leaking-outside-work